# When to use “de” before a verb in infinitive form?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, prépositions, infinitif

Which of this is correct?

> Est-ce que tu aimes aller au théâtre?
>
> Est-ce que tu aimes d'aller au théâtre?

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: And what are the cases in which «d'aller» is correct, please? Can you give examples?

Comment: J'ai envie d'aller au théâtre.

Comment: `d'aller` is use after an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so I understand. Usage of *de* depends not on the verb *aller* but on the main verb. It could be for example *décider de*, *finir de*, *avoir envie/horreur/besoin de*, etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right.